# bitbucket and TFS - any 3rd party opensource tools to connect or integrate between these 2 repositories

Tags: tfs, connection, bitbucket, integrator

Currently my On-premise company is using Team Foundation Server (TFS), it is doing multiple things like work tracking and build.
We brought Bitbucket to separate code repository, we still want to continue using TFS for work tracking. We are looking for any (opensource project examples) connectors or integrators or plugins somewhat similar to connect between Bitbucket & TFS . If there is any opensource project examples to connect these somewhat similar will try to tweak it.

Comment: Could you elaborate how do you want to integrate bitbucket with TFS, share code or build bitbucket repo in TFS? Which version of TFS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Pipelines, Azure DevOps Server, and TFS integrate with a number of version control systems. When you use any of these version control systems, you can configure a pipeline to build, test, and deploy your application. Please check [Supported source repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/?view=azure-devops) of Azure DevOps Server/TFS.

`Bitbucket Cloud` repository type is supported in Azure Pipelines, but not in on-premise Azure DevOps Server/TFS. As a workaround, you can use the **Other Git**  or **External Git** repository type in on-premise Azure DevOps Server/TFS, to build repositories in Bitbucket.